# titlesec space after paragraph name

Tags: spacing, titlesec

I'm using the package `titlesec` to modify spacing before and after headings.

Using `\titlespacing\paragraph` makes the paragraph *text* appear directly after the paragraph *title* - I would like there to be a horizontal space of around .4cm. How do I achieve this?

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titlespacing\paragraph{0pt}{0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

\begin{document}
    \paragraph{Paragraph title} \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{2ex}{0.4cm}` should do it:

- the first argument is wgat's added to the left margin before the paragraph title begins;
- the second argument is the vertical spacing added to the normal base line skip w.r.t. the previous text;
- the third argument  is the spacing w.r.t. the following text (usually vertical, but horizontal in the `runin` style,  which the default style for \paragraph).